# Can you use Fabricate on 13 Adamantine crossbow bolts to make a short sword?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, crafting, special-materials

Can you use the Fabricate spell on 13 adamantine crossbow bolts to make a short sword?

The average crossbow bolt is 15-22 inch long and avg. diameter of 0.003 inch – about 0.14 pounds each, coming to roughly 1.82 pounds. Is that enough material to fabricate into a short sword? A short sword weighs about 2 pounds, I'm assuming, with hand wraps and pommel.

Answer (score 5):

**Can you use Fabricate to convert crossbow bolts to make a short sword: maybe.**
**Do 13 crossbow bolts have enough metal to create a short sword: no.**

Overall yes, you should be able to, assuming you have the relevant proficiency per the spell and your DM doesn't rule that "convert raw materials into products of the same material" necessarily requires converting unworked material. "Raw materials" isn't well-defined in the spell, and quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_material), fully-worked bolts may not qualify:

> The term raw material denotes materials in unprocessed or minimally processed states; e.g., raw latex, crude oil, cotton, coal, raw biomass, iron ore, air, logs, water, or "any product of agriculture, forestry, fishing or mineral in its natural form or which has undergone the transformation required to prepare it for international marketing in substantial volumes". The term secondary raw material denotes waste material which has been recycled and injected back into use as productive material.

Double check with your DM (or make a judgment call if you're the DM), since they could potentially rule that you could convert adamantine ore into a sword, but not necessarily convert worked material.

As for the sizing:

> The average crossbow bolt is 15-22 inch long and avg. diameter of 0.003 inch – about 0.14 pounds each, coming to roughly 1.82 pounds.

Crossbow bolts in 5e have a RAW weight, 0.075lbs (1.5lbs for 20). Crossbow bolts were typically not made entirely of metal; you can see examples of crossbow bolts [here](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/33754). Like arrows, they have wooden shafts and only have metal heads:
[image]

The exact proportion of metal to wood isn't defined anywhere for the game, but if you take half the weight as the bolt head, you have 0.0375lbs of metal per bolt. A shortsword weighs 2lbs, so you'd need 53.33 bolts (assuming the non-metal portions of the sword are negligible in weight). Using adamantine would affect both weights proportionally, so the same ratio would apply.

Comment: Where is the rule for that? The spell doesn't mention the value of the inputs or outputs, unless you take "the quality of objects made by the spell is commensurate with the quality of the raw materials" to mean "value in must equal value out" rather than "using partially-rotten timber creates a partially-rotten bridge." Is there a general rule that's specified outside the spell?

Comment: I misread the tags and thought this was a 3.5e question

Answer (score 2):

You need to fulfill several requirements, but otherwise yes, your desired usage will work. First you need the correct proficiency for weapons as stated in the spell description.

Taken from the [spell description](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Fabricate#content)

> Creatures or magic items can't be created or transmuted by this spell. You also can't use it to create items that ordinarily require a high degree of craftsmanship, such as jewelry, **Weapons**, glass, or armor, unless you have proficiency with the type of artisan's tools used to craft such Objects.

Next you need the correct materials, and I'm going to just say your main concern is the primary metal of the sword and nothing else. Now, first we see that both the [sword](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Shortsword#content) and [bolts](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Crossbow%20bolts#content) are steel, which isn't the same weight as your metal. Listed [here](https://olddungeonmaster.com/2016/12/06/dd-5e-weights-of-materials/) its about 4/5 of the weight. So the sword becomes 2/(5/4)=1.6 and each bolt is 0.075/(5/4)=0.06.

So for your 1.6 pound sword, using 0.06 bolts, you need 1.6/0.06=26.666 bolts (which is actually the same amount as if we just used the values for steel).

Comment: Well DM said that bolts are solid adamantine bolts which means that you can melt down all 13 bolts  and make an ingot out of it, thus turning it now to a "raw matterial". Metal ingots are raw materials tht can be turned to weapons or armor. Can even add addition metals to (sadly diluting the adamantine) if more material is need to craft the item in question. Thank you this was the most helpfull answer we got and so far quelled our players' arguments.

Comment: How do you address the fact that the spell requires raw material?

Comment: Ingots of metals are raw matterial as you still have to heat and treat the metal. This process you add other materials like flux durinng the the process of folding the heated ingot. Durrign the folding procces you draw out the impurities from the ingot making the metal in this case adamatine stronger.

Comment: Just turning the adamantine to a single bar of metal to adds things to the metal like excess carbon that if not properly handled will make the metal brittle.  You are pretty much reverse engineering the finish productto its raw -like state, give or take waht is lost /gained in smelting it. So first smelt the bolts in to ingot/s, fabricate weapon from ingot, add guard, pummle and hand wraps.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Thanks for the explanation, but I was asking to Fering, tio address this issue in their answer. This "ingot strategy" is indeed interesting, but you should have included in your question.

Comment: @Eddymage Why cant a finished product still count as a raw material if those resources are recoverable? Its not like an egg has been added to a cake. This is just metal.

Comment: Beacuse they do not satisfy the definition of "raw material". The adamantine has been forged and shaped into an arrowhead: this is far away to be raw, *i.e.* to be a piece of adamantine ore. If you look at the examples provided in the spell description, it is quite clear what "raw" means in this case.

Comment: I tend to disagree; "raw material" is situational. If you looked at a tumbledown shack and said, "I can use the wood here as raw materials", nobody would think you were using the term incorrectly.  Provided there's a way a craftsman could turn the source into the target, the spell should be able to, too.  You could easily turn a wood-framed house into a bridge, but not a wagonload of cuckoo clocks. Not because the clocks aren't "raw enough", but because the wood is in bits too small to serve as structural members.

Answer (score -1):

#### Crossbow bolts are not raw materials.

*Fabricate* says:

> You convert raw materials into products of the same material. For example, you can fabricate a wooden bridge from a clump of trees, a rope from a patch of hemp, and clothes from flax or wool.

Crossbow bolts are manufactured items. Notice the examples - “clump of trees”, “patch of hemp”, “flax or wool” - all of these are materials as they naturally occur. Crossbow bolts are not raw materials.

#### By my math, 13 adamantine crossbow bolts is worth about 1.3 adamantine short swords.

The rules for adamantine weapons say:

> The adamantine version of a melee weapon or of ten pieces of ammunition costs 500 gp more than the normal version, whether the weapon or ammunition is made of the metal or coated with it.

The rules do not even begin to touch the math you attempt to calculate in the question. An adamantine weapon is worth 500 gp plus its usual price. The price of 1 adamantine short swords and 13 adamantine crossbow bolts is actually pretty similar. Just sell the bolts and buy the sword.

Comment: Raw materials is a badly defined concept though. If you treat anything that has been processed in any way as not being "raw" then you can't chop down a tree then use fabricate on it as it has been processed by means of being chopped down.

Comment: @AllanMills The difference between finely crafted crossbow bolts and a tree that has only just been cut down seems pretty clear to me.